# C# SQL Collation In SQL select for multi user

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a created a c# application in WinForms, where multiple users will be selecting records from sql and edit as per physical form.
I want to lock record which is in use by one user. I have tried multiple options but the still sometime the same record is visible in two or three users machine.

My C# Code To retrieve, update, select and display record.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("get_First_Unscan_Record_withUpdate",conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrName", username_Form);
        conn.Open();
        record_number = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
}


SqlParameter[] SQlparams =
{
    new SqlParameter("@srno",SqlDbType.NVarChar,50) {Value=record_number.ToString()}
};

SqlDataReader dr = DM.GetDataReader("get_Record_with_Srno", SQlparams);
```

My SQL Store Procedure

```
Declare @srno int

update KYC_Index 
set   [transform_int] = 'Y',
      [transform_int_by] = 'Danish',    
      [transform_int_time] = GETDATE(),
      @srno = srno
where srno = (select C.srno 
              from   (select top 1 srno,
                                   index_Filename  
                      FROM [KYC].[dbo].[KYC_Index] B 
                      where B.[transform_int] = 'N' 
                      and   B.transform_status = 'N' 
                      order by B.index_Filename, B.srno
                     ) C
             )  

select @srno
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you just trying to lock it while its on someones screen or just while you update..

Comment: @BugFinder I want to lock it while its on someone screen

Comment: then your app is behaving as it should - locks are to prevent updates at the same time, if you need to block people from viewing an edit screen on the same record - then  you need to make that

Comment: @BugFinder can you suggest me what should I do

Comment: how is mysql involved with this question ?

Comment: @GuidoG removed.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to lock records that are just being viewed.

The obvious way to do this is to add another column, say a bit column like IsViewing, and when a user opens a record you set this to 1, marking it as locked.

When they update or move away from a record, you set it to 0, marking it as unlocked.

But consider 2 users, A & B.

A opens a record. B simultaneously opens the same record.

User A's app checks the record & finds it unlocked.
User B's app also does a check & finds it unlocked.

User A's app set the IsViewing flag to 1. User B's app does the same. Now you're back where you started.

Consider also the case that the record gets locked, and the app terminates abnormally, say via task manager or loss of network, without unlocking the record.

Now you have to think about how to handle those records.

A simple solution is to add a timestamp column.

When you read a record, you have it's timestamp.
When the user tries to update, compare the timestamp in your app to the current timestamp. If they are different, you know the record has changed & can prompt the user for how to merge changes.
You could also periodically check the timestamp while the record is open & notify the user if there has been an edit.

Comment: I did something similar. Check my SQL procedure. I am updating my field [transform_int] = 'Y' which is a char field  and also has a where clause [transform_int] = 'N'. Still, as the application is being accessed by more than 20 users I am getting cases of collation.